# Load Values From Closed Workbook Into Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have not used VBA in a while so I'm a bit rusty. Seeking help.

The task:
I need to pull all unique value from a given range in a closed workbook, into my sub's workbook. 
I'm thinking of calling a function that returns an array of my unique non-blank values. because I need to know the quantity of unique values to insert the right amount of lines in the main workbook. Can't juts copy-paste the values. And also because I need to remove the duplicates.

Some relevant code bits up to know:

```
    Sub PullACParts()

    Dim FullFilePath As String
    Dim arrPartList() As String  

FullFilePath = "C:\Users\[...]file1.xlsx"
arrPartList() = GetValues(FullFilePath)
```

and that calls:

```
Function GetValues(path as string) as Variant
    Dim arrValues() As String
    Dim arrUnikVals As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim src As Workbook

    ' OPEN THE SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK IN "READ ONLY MODE".
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(FullFilePath, True, True)

    ' GET THE TOTAL ROWS FROM THE SOURCE WORKBOOK.
    Dim iTotalRows As Integer
    TotalRows = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count

    ' COPY NON-BLANK DATA FROM SOURCE FILE COLUMN-4 TO ARRAY.
    Dim iCnt As Integer         ' COUNTER.
    Dim ArrDim As Long: ArrDim = 0

    For iCnt = 4 To TotalRows

        If src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & iCnt).Value <> "" Then
            arrValues(ArrDim) = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4 & iCnt).Formula 'FAILS HERE
            ArrDim = ArrDim + 1
        End If

    Next iCnt

    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    src.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set src = Nothing

    ' Remove Duplicates
    arrUnikVals = RemoveDupesColl(arrValues)
    GetValues = arrUnikVals

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

It fails when I try loading the array. Says "arrValues(ArrDim) = 
I tried a few different things but just can't figure it out. 
Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Exactly how does it fail? What error are you getting? - always helps to include that in a post. You've declared `arrValues()` but you've not given it a size - it will not auto-size as you add elements.

Comment: `arrValues(ArrDim)` this will fail, you need to `redim` the array.  The range itself is an array though.  So `arrValues=range("a1:a10")` can be said

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop this. First set your variable types.

```
Dim arrValue as Variant, lr as long
```

Once this is a variant you can simply grab the array from the range in one go by transposing it:

```
lr = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("D" & rows.count).end(xlup).row
Application.transpose(src.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("D4:D" & lr))
```

If you need to loop the values in the array later you simply do something like this:

```
Dim X as long
For X = lbound(arrValue) to ubound(arrValue)
    msgbox arrValue(X)
next
```

I do however note in your question you say you want to pull data from a CLOSED workbook but your code is opening the book. There are ways to pull data direct from a closed book but it would be difficult because you don't know how many rows it will be without opening the book. If you absolutely have to leave the book closed then post back.

I also note you are using cells(4 & iCnt) to try and populate the array, you do know that is just the cell counting from left to right then row to row? in other words cells(2) is B1 and cells(16386) is B2. You should use cells(Row,Column) I think from what you have said you want to increment the row but if not then post back, we simply double transpose if it's across columns instead of rows.

Comment: OP is only collecting values from non-blank cells though, which is maybe why they didn't do this?

Comment: Ahhhh my bad, I missed that part. I would probably still grab the range in one go then remove the blanks when looping the array. 6 of one, half a dozen of the other I suppose.

Comment: In fact maybe the could even put a line in their function that dedupes the array elements to remove blanks

Comment: Another alternative would be to copy the range, dump it in a temp worksheet, use Excels remove duplicates function, copy the range back to an array, this would remove the blanks also.